# Dynamically Add View To Fragment Outside OnCreateView Call

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, viewgroup

I have looked at about 12 SO posts, and read the documentation on both Activities and Fragments.

I have what I *think* is an incredibly common issue but perhaps I'm missing something fundamental.

I have a fragment. This fragment is creating its view from Java not from XML. During runtime, I want to add an image to it. I've tried adding the view to the viewgroupd, creating a LinearLayout and adding it to the view, and a few other things but none of them work. I often get a crash (with NO error log :?().

Here is my best attempted code:

```
iImage image = new iImage(getActivity());
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
((ViewGroup)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(resourceId).getView()).addView(image);
```

If you can advise how I can just add a view to the fragment I would GREATLY appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an incredibly common problem. The solution is to keep a private variable to your inflated view and you can use it later... where ever that may be. In this example I am assuming that your root layout (the top most element in your XML)  is `LinearLayout`

```
public class DummyFragment extends Fragment {

    private LinearLayout root;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout = (LinearLayout)  inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_fragment_layout, container, false);
        return root;
    }

}
```

Comment: But can't I access that dynamically? Why must I store it? Do I HAVE to inflate a view that way?

Comment: You do not need to inflate the View in the onCreateView... onCreateView is just a method that is called by activity to tell your fragment to prepare it's initial layout. You only need to return a view. There you can create a dummy view group and keep a reference to it for later use, then you can dynamically add views to it. But since most people use XML for their layouts, google was kind enough to provide us with an inflater

Comment: Ok I think we are getting somewhere. The only thing is View seems abstract. I can't add a view to a view. It needs to be something? I am trying to cast it as a ViewGroup but its not working.

Comment: Omg %_% finally. Thank so much. Coming from iOS I'm having a hard time getting used to doing things the way I'd like on Android. You know how to add a view to a view on iOS? view.addViewI(). Everything on android strikes me as excessively needlessly over complex and bloated..:/

Comment: I have done a project or two on iOS and lost my patience with the damn auto layout for a few times until I finally turned that crap off. I'm sure you know what I mean :D

Comment: Storyboards are garbage. I stripped them from my project and havent looked back. I make all my views from JSON. And hence also what I'm trying to do on Android too. I think XML is also garbage, and I want my views to be made all from JSON so I need to create all my objects in Java (hence this question haha)